# Match regex with Uppercase

Tags: regex

I need to match string that starts with uppercase like A, BBB, C, Cela, BLE.

Just the upper case is important.

Trying out I reach this result

```
\^[A-Z]\w+\gm
```

but the thing is I'm getting the correct result but not catch just a single string like A, B, C.

what could it be?

thank you!

Comment: If you're looking to only match alpha characters, use `^[A-Z][^\W\d_]*\b` - `\w` matches alpha, digits and `_`

Answer (score 3):

You were very close to the right solution. The problem is that your pattern will only match strings with *2* or more characters due to the `+` quantifier after the `\w`. Instead, use `*` to match any number of word characters following the initial capital letter.

`\^[A-Z]\w*\gm`

Answer (score 3):

You need another quantifier:

```
\^[A-Z]\w*\gm
#       ^^^
```

The star (`*`) means "zero or more of the thing in front".